# Validate String if The String Matches with Two Keywords

Tags: c, validation

I'm trying to make a program where there will be string validation with `strcmp()` where the program will only receive "yes" or "no". I thought that this *do-while* loop should be able to do the trick:

```
char input[11];

do
{
    printf("Would you like some coffee[yes/no]: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", input);
    fflush(stdin);
}while (strcmp(input, "yes") != 0 || strcmp(input,"no") != 0);

if(strcmp(input, "yes") == 0)
{
    printf("Here is the coffee.\n");
}

else
{
    printf("What a shame.\n");
}
```

However when I tested it out, the loop wouldn't stop. I do suspect that it is caused by difference of string length, but I feel like I am missing something else. Is there is another alternative to validate the string such that it can validate whether it is "yes" or "no"? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `||` should be `&&`

Comment: thanks @kaylum. Sorry for the fuss....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `strcmp` function returns nonzero when the two given strings are unequal.  So your condition says "loop as long as input is not 'yes' OR input is not 'no'".

If the input is "yes", the first part is false but the second part is true, so the whole condition is true.  The same goes for if the input is "no".  So you have an infinite loop.

You want to loop if the string is not "yes" AND the string is not "no".

```
}while (strcmp(input, "yes") != 0 && strcmp(input,"no") != 0);
```